# Aws - Event Bridge to Pyhonshell script(glue)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

My requirement is to convert csv file to parquet file as soon as the file recieve at source S3 bucket.For that I have created python shell script (glue) and automated the job using event bridge. Below is my flow

Source S3 bucket(csv) -> Event Bridge-> Workflow -> Python shell (Glue job) -> Destination S3 bucket(parquet)

I required source bucket name, folder and csv file name dynamically in python shell script(glue job) from event bridge.

Note : in event bridge, there is also cloud log group as a target. In cloud watch log group I can get bucket name, folder and file name which is in process. The same details i need in glue job.

Please help

I cant use lambda function as per the policy, instead of lambda is there any option how to get source bucket name, folder and csv file name in glue.